# How to get all bundle products where simple is a part. Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

Guys I need to know how I can display on a common product page all the bundle products it is part of. I tried a few ways I found on the internet but nothing worked correctly. I need this done for magento 1. Does anyone know how this could be done?